# It is probably because somebody "told" him that he "had" a very good physique. - is this the conditional usage?

Tags: tense, conditionals

**Example 1**

> A: Why is he working out so hard?

> B: It is probably because somebody **told** him that he **had** a very good physique.

**Example 2**

> A: Why is he smiling?

> B: I don't know. He is smiling probably because he **met** a girl who **told** him that he **had** a very good physique.

The reasons (because-clauses) are my guesses, so they can be imaginary.

So this got me to think: Does this kind of structure have anything to do with a second or third conditional structure or are they just normal past tense?

Are parts in bold correct?

Comment: The parts in bold are correct, but I'm confused as to why you think they might not be.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing conditional in your example.

"Told" and "met" are in the past because they happened in the past.

"Had" is in the past because it's *indirect speech*. In indirect speech, we often *backshift* the verb tenses that were originally said to indicate that you're not asserting any of this to be true, just reflecting what someone else said.